# Laplacian in Polar Coordinates: $\nabla^2f(r)=f''(r)+\frac{2}{r}f'(r)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, polar-coordinates

> $\vec{R}=x \hat{i} + y\hat{j} + z\hat{k}$ and
>   $r=|\vec{R}|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$
>
> Prove that $\nabla^2f(r)=f''(r)+\frac{2}{r}f'(r)$

So we need to basically show that $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f(r)+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}f(r)+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}f(r)=\frac{d^2f}{dr^2}+\frac{2}{r}\frac{df}{dr}$$

$f(r)$ is a scalar function of $r$.

I'm not sure how to go about proving this. How can we possibly express $\frac{d^2f}{dr^2}$ and $\frac{df}{dr}$ in terms of $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f(r)$, $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}f(r)$ and $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}f(r)$ ?

Comment: $
\nabla^2 f(r) = \nabla \cdot \nabla f(r) = \nabla\cdot\left(\frac{\vec{R}}{r} f'(r)\right)
= \frac{\nabla\cdot \vec{R}}{r}f'(r) + \vec{R}\cdot\nabla\left(\frac{1}{r}f'(r)\right) = \cdots $

Comment: @achillehui Thanks. But I don't know why $\nabla f(r) = \frac{\vec{R}}{r}f'(r)$. Can you point me to the proof of that part?

Comment: recall what is $\nabla f$ geometrically, it is a vector pointing to the direction where the $f$ changes the quickest. When $f$ depends only on $r$, that direction is the radial directon. i.e. in the direction of the unit vector  ${\rm sign}(f'(r)) \frac{\vec{R}}{r}$. For the second step, it is the ordinary rule $(gh)' = g'h+ gh'$ applied to each component and then reexpress it in terms of vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using the chain rule, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{d f}{dr}\cdot\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}
\end{aligned}
$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{d f}{dr}\right)\cdot\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+\frac{d f}{dr}\cdot\frac{\partial ^2r}{\partial x^2}\\
&=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r^2}\cdot\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right)^2+\frac{d f}{dr}\cdot\frac{\partial ^2r}{\partial x^2}\\
&=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r^2}\cdot\left(\frac{x}{r}\right)^2+\frac{d f}{dr}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{x^2}{r^3}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2}&=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r^2}\cdot\left[\left(\frac{x}{r}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{r}\right)^2+\left(\frac{z}{r}\right)^2\right]\\
&+\frac{d f}{dr}\cdot\left(\frac{3}{r}-\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{r^3}\right)\\
&=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r^2}+\frac{2}{r}\frac{df}{dr}
\end{aligned}
$$